# How to convert mongodb data encrypted with Gibberish to RbNaCl

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, rake

I took over a ROR/MongoDB project that is using Gibberish w/ Mongoid::EncryptedFields

Gibberish is outdated and not supported anymore. The entire database data is encrypted with Gibberish using something like the following.

```
Mongoid::EncryptedFields.cipher_same_salt = GibberishCipher1.new(ENV['MONGODB_SAME_SALT_KEY'], ENV['MONGODB_SALT'])
```

I am trying to switch to RbNaCl SimpleBox. My question is when I switch to RbNaCl if I try to pull a view it will need to decrypt the data to show the user. How can I get RbNaCl to decrypt the data that was encrypted with Gibberish? Gibberish encrypted it with Salt

`@cipher.encrypt(text, salt: @salt)`

Can I create a RAKE task that opens each MongoDB record, decrypts it and then resave it without encryption? We have about 40 entities and a total of 1.5M records.

Comment: A brief look at docs for both gems leads me to believe this won't be an easy task if even it is possible.  Why not just decrypt the data with Gibberish before trying to switch out your cryptography tools ?

Comment: It appears Gibberish isn't supported anymore. At some point, it will be deprecated when we update to the next version of ROR at which time our data will be useless. I am wondering if their is a way to create a bot or worker to open each mongoDB entity then decrypt the data and resave without encryption.

Comment: are you able to run any version of Gibberish?  Can you do the decryption in one go or is the DB live?

Comment: The old version, but prevents upgrade. Wrote a decrypt rake task and then saving fields to new fields. Then another rake task to put new fields in old fields after removing encryption code.